# creating a lisp function that gives a list of even number from a list

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I would like to create a function for class that would take two arguments `L` and `L1` as lists and put all even numbers from `L` into `L1`.

I've tried for several hours to make it work, but unfortunatelly I couldn't.

This is my Scheme code:

```lisp
(define (pair L L1)
  (cond
   ((and (not (empty? L)) (= (modulo (first L) 2) 0))
    (begin (append (list (first L)) L1) (pair (rest L) L1)))
   ((and (not (empty? L)) (= (modulo (first L) 2) 1))
    (pair (rest L) L1))
   (else L1)
   ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to use `L1` as an accumulator, and at the end return its content.

About your code:

1. It's enough to check once in the first clause of `cond` if `L` is empty (`null?`).
2. `append` is fine when you want to append a list. In your case you append one element, so `cons` is much better.
3. You don't have to take `modulo` of a number, to check if it's even. There is build in `even?` predicate.

So, after all this considerations, your code should look something like this:

```lisp
(define (pair L L1)
  (cond ((null? L) L1)
        ((even? (first L))
         (pair (rest L) (cons (first L) L1)))
        (else (pair (rest L) L1))))
```

Now let's test it:

```lisp
> (pair '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7) '())
(6 4 2 0)
```

As you can see, it returns numbers in reverse order. It's because as we move down the list `L` from head to tail, we `cons` new values to the head (and not tail, like `append` would) of the list `L1`. To fix it, it's enough to `(reverse L1)` in the first `cond` clause instead of simply returning `L1`.

I highly recommend *"Little Schemer"* book. After reading it, you will be able to write any kind of recursive functions even in your sleep ;)

Comment: thank you so much sir this answer was extremely enriching as it's my first time working with lisp